# .NET Core FDD SDC at the same time

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

When switching from FDD to SDC, you have to:

> 3. Open the project.json file and in the frameworks section, remove the following line:
>
>    ```
>    "type": "platform",
>    ```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index

But what if I want to distribute my app as both FDD and SDC? (I build 2 versions, users choose which one they want.) Is it possible without changing project.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, as at least right now you cannot use any conditions in `project.json` - .NET Core team tries to keep it fully declarative (see [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3173) on github). But you can create 2 separate `project.json` files and 
publishe the application using the specified one.

For example, use your default project.json for FDD and put another one for SDC in separate folder, then use

```
dotnet publish ~/projects/app1/project.json
```

or even default

```
dotnet publish
```

for FDD and next one for SDC:

```
dotnet publish ~/projects/app1/SDC/project.json
```

Comment: "at least right now you cannot use any conditions in `project.json`" That certainly won't be changed in the future, since project.json is being replaced with msbuild.